# How to Authenticate API for creating pod using Kubernetes certificates

Tags: kubernetes, client-certificates, kubernetes-pod, fabric8

Query: I want to authenticate users for a REST API(Creating pods) using certificates in Kubernetes.

So far: I have created the user's crt file, private key file, added roles in roles.YAML file and did role binding in YAML file and added that user in the config file as well. If I try to create a pod with the same user using terminal commands in that namespace. then that user is given an error (Permission denied) which is correct as no permission was given to this user for creating a pod.

Problem: I want to do the same thing in spring boot application but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: the spring boot application will run inside kubernetes cluster or outside of it

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking for. Are you asking for sprinboot code on how to implement it or how to setup k8s permisions? Or maybe sth else?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu inside Kubernetes cluster

Comment: @HelloWorld I'm asking how can I use certificates which are created like ca.crt, ca.key in spring boot application for Authenticating

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [fabric8 kubernetes client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) or [kubernetes java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) library in the spring boot application and use a service account(recommended) or kubeconfig file to invoke kubernetes APIs.

Comment: I'm already using fabric8 Kubernetes client dependency. created an API also but don't know how to  authenticate cluster on the user basis>if you have any code regarding that can you please share